# Web view back button history

Tags: ios, swift, webview, navigation, back

How do I create a back button in Swift for my web view which functions like the one on the News app on my phone? 
When the user navigates within the web view, the back button will return to the previous web page in the web view. When the user goes back to the original landing page, the same back button will close the web view and return to the application. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

=>here is one of code and make sure you will have to confirm delegate of webView:

@IBAction func goBack(AnyObject) {

webView.goBack()

}

Comment: The button is working but just to go back in the web view. Am I missing something to make it dismiss the web view view controller and return to the previous one? Thanks.